# How many nonisomorphic graphs are there with 10 vertices and 43 edges?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

How would I go about solving this?

I know that $K_{10}$ has $9+8+7+\dots+1=45$ edges.

So would it be something like $\binom {45}{43}$ because out of the 45 total edges, one must choose 43 for the graph?

Second attempt:
At least for the second bullet point mentioned, it seems that there would be $\binom{10}{2}9\cdot7$ ways. There are two vertices to choose from ten. Then, for the first vertex, there are nine options for a connecting vertex, and for the second vertex, there are 7 options for a connecting vertex.}

Third attempt: I don't know what I was thinking ^. I can only find one non-isomorphic class for the second bullet point, and they are not isomorphic those in the first class.

Answer (score 4):

HINTS: The question is: how many non-isomorphic graphs can you get by removing two edges from $K_{10}$?

- You can remove two edges that share a vertex. There are $10\binom92=360$ ways to do this, so you get $360$ graphs, but you should be able to show that they are all isomorphic.
- You can remove two edges that do not share a vertex. Are all of the resulting graphs isomorphic to one another? Are they isomorphic to those of the first type?

**Added:** As DKal suggested in the comments, it may be helpful to look at the complements of the resulting graphs, if you already know (or can figure out how to prove) that two graphs are isomorphic if and only if their complements are isomorphic.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the former are all isomorphic but not all of the latter are?

Comment: @Joel: I didn’t say that the graphs in the second bullet point are not all isomorphic; I left it for you to determine. The argument that those in the first bullet point are all isomorphic is really very straightforward, and you really ought to think about it for a bit before giving up on it.

Comment: @joel, It might be easier to see if you consider the complement graph. It has $10$ vertices and $2$ edges. How many non-isomorphic graphs are there with $2$ edges? Of course, you should note that you are using the fact that two graphs are isomorphic iff their complements are.

Comment: I think I like this framing better.

Comment: One thing that's tripping me up is that I'm not sure what it means for one graph to be isomorphic. It's usually in the context of two graphs. Is it asking for the number of "non-isomorphic classes"?

Comment: @Joel: There’s nothing here about one graph being isomorphic; as you say, that doesn’t make sense. Take all of the graphs that you can obtain from $K_{10}$ by deleting two edges. The relation of isomorphism is an equivalence relation on this set of graphs; how many equivalence classes are there? In other words, what’s the maximum number of pairwise non-isomorphic graphs that you can get in this way — a set of graphs in which no two are isomorphic to each other?

Comment: So, as clarification, the graphs in bullet point one would still count as one non-isomorphic graph, correct? I've made some revisions to my solution.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Is my third attempt sound?

Comment: @Joel: It’s the correct number, though I to answer the question completely you’d have to prove that each of the two operations yields only one equivalence class, and that the two classes are distinct.